# Migrations are pending

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite3

Sou novo com Rails e estou aprendendo também a utilizar banco de dados. Estou tentando criar um blog que tem no momento uma tabela que já contém alguns dados. O que acontece é que eu estava utilizando o notebook para desenvolver o blog e agora quando clonei do git para o meu PC, os dados que eu tinha na tabela sumiram. Quando eu rodo `rails server` recebo esse erro:

```
Migrations are pending.
To resolve this issue, run: bin/rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development".
```

Ao rodar esse código ele cria uma tabela sem os dados que eu já tinha nela. O que estou fazendo de errado e como posso recuperar os dados?

Comment: mas onde que tá o arquivo da database? se estiver fora do seu repositório git não vai subir no commit mesmo (se tiver no gitignore tb)

Comment: Consegui resolver utilizando essa gem : https://github.com/rroblak/seed_dump. Básicamente ele gravou os dados no arquivo seeds.rb e depois preencheu a tabela para mim. Muito obrigado xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro que você recebeu indica que existem migrações que o seu banco de dados ainda não aplicou. Como você disse, você havia trocado de computador.

O banco de dados é **local** e **não é** versionado pelo Git, por motivos claros. Pelo que me parece, você está usando SQLite, o que facilita a troca de ambientes. Só precisa copiar o arquivo `db/development.sqlite3` de um ambiente pro outro. Este arquivo é por padrão ignorado no `.gitignore` criado pelo Rails, pois não deve ser *commitado*.

Se você estivesse usando outro DBMS, como MySQL ou PostgreSQL, teria que criar um backup do banco e carregá-lo no outro ambiente.

O arquivo de [seed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_seeding) não serve para "criar um backup" do banco, e sim, uma versão limpa e inicial da aplicação. Isto é, preencher uma tabela de cidades, países, criar um usuário administrador, e outras coisas do tipo.

Comment: Entendi Vinicius, agradeço muito pela sua orientação.